# Mac OS X: can I install/uninstall software for one user only?

Tags: macos, mac

There are two admin user accounts on my MacBook. I want to install different versions of a software program (OmniGraffle) on each user account. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just copy the application into the home directory of each user.  I usually have an user specific Applications directory for each user, in their own directory. So you would have

/Users/user1/Applications/OmniGraffle

/Users/user2/Applications/OmniGraffle

You can also rename the application directory (add the version number), and make both versions available from the system Applications folder.

/Applications/OmniGraffle4

/Applications/OmniGraffle5